# How to parse this specific type of data in excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, parsing

I have a bunch of different sets of engineering measurements in the format:

77.170 (+/- 0.025)

And I need to split it into the first number, which is the nominal value, and the number in the parenthesis, the tolerance. Not sure exactly how to do this in excel VBA. I was thinking I would use the Split function with a space delimiter, giving me the first number, then the unnecessary characters, then the tolerance, but the tolerance will include a parenthesis. How could I get rid of just that parenthesis, and will what I just suggested even work? Thanks!

Comment: You want `77.170 (+/- 0.025)` to become `77.170 +/- 0.025` right? Are the nominal and tolerance in the same cell? The outcome should be in 1 or 2 cells?

Comment: No, I want to seperate it into two different variables in VBA, where one variable will be just the first number, and the second will be just the second. I dont need the +/- for anything. Sorry that this was unclear.

Comment: Please consider my suggested improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    s = "77.170 (+/- 0.025)"
    s2 = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, " ", ""), "+/-", ""), ")", "")
    ary = Split(s2, "(")
    MsgBox ary(0) & vbCrLf & ary(1)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer! I think this will probably work for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Text to Columns and a formula.

Go to Data--->Text to Columns. Choose delimited and choose Space as your delimiter. This should split the text string into something like:

```
ColA  |ColB|ColC
77.170|(+/-|0.025)
```

Column C is a bit funky, so let's just grab everything but the last character.

In column D put this:

```
=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-1)
```

Finally, you should get:

```
ColA  |ColB |ColC  |ColD |
77.170|(+/- |0.025)|0.025|
```

Comment: Thanks, this might work, but I cant change the document I'm working on. I need to store it in variables so I can manipulate it and use it on a seperate workbook. This would change the document the information is on, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of instr() and mid to get what you need. For example

```
measurments="77.170 (+/- 0.025)"
mid(measurements,1,instr(measurements," "))
trim(mid(measurements,instr(measurements,"-")+1,instr(measurements,")")-instr(measurements,"-")-1))
```

or, to combine,

```
measurments="77.170 (+/- 0.025)"
mid(measurements,1,instr(measurements," ")) & " " & trim(mid(measurements,instr(measurements,"-")+1,instr(measurements,")")-instr(measurements,"-")-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of [InStr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php), [Left()](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php), Right().

Get the index/position of the '(' using InStr and then extract the characters using Left and Right. If you want to get the final data as a double or a Long use CDbl() or CLng() respectively.

Answer (score 0):

For getting text out of other text consider using Regular Expresions.
To use them in VBA you will need in Reference 'VBScript_RegExp_55' library.

The reason why you might want to do that is because following code returns whatever first two numbers show up in your text( it can be modified to be much smarter than that), regardless of other text around it.

```
Dim Regex As RegExp
Dim Matches As MatchCollection

Set Regex = New RegExp
Regex.Pattern = "\d*\.\d*"
Regex.Global = True

Set Matches = Regex.Execute("77.170 (+/- 0.025)")

MsgBox (Matches(0).Value & " " & Matches(1).Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming s is your measurement string, here is the most direct way:

```
v = Split(Left(s, Len(s) - 1), " (+/- ")
```

That's it. Now v(0) holds the nominal value and v(1) holds the tolerance.